# Which AWS Lambda template to use in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I am new AWS Lambda functions development. After exploring a few articles & video, I decided to get started with real-time development.

This is the requirement created.

- Create a Lambda function that would run sometime of every day
- This function would fetch customers from DynamoDb
- The above fetched customers would be send an email

Now when I opened `Visual Studio 2017` with `AWS SDK` installed. It popped up with 2 templates.

1. AWS Lambda Project (.Net Core)
2. AWS Serverless Application (.Net Core)

I googled around these templates but couldn't find any article/link which could explain what are these templates for. And When to use which?

As per requirement stated which template would best fit & Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Option #1 is for a normal Lambda project, such as building a quick function. There is no framework for defining and linking resources.

Use #2 (AWS Serverless Application) if you want to build a SAM ([Serverless Application Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html)) app. This includes a layer on top of CloudFormation called SAM templates, and SAM apps also include a local testing and debugging rig. Here is some information about [SAM and visual studio](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-serverless-applications-in-visual-studio/).

If you are defining and orchestrating several different serverless components as part of your project, consider using SAM. It will make deployments easily repeatable across environments thanks to CloudFormation. If you are already using cfn for your resources, consider this option.

For your use case, both will work, but I recommended trying out SAM to make local testing and debugging easier since you are new to Lambda.

Comment: Thanks! but as far as I understood SAM always have resources loaded that could lead to extra charge while other option #1 loads in memory only when hit & used. This would be cost efficient. how much correct is this?

Comment: SAM is a framework/toolchain that makes defining, packaging, and deploying your serverless applications easier. It doesn't change the pricing or require any additional resources to be deployed.